# What's App sharing files

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I’m currently developing an iOS application (with Swift 3). In order to improve the user experience for the sharing, I would like to integrate What’s App.

Indeed, after some actions, the user can, if he wants, share a PDF file with UIActivityViewController.

To assure the best user experience possible, it would be amazing if the user could share directly to a phone number with What's App (without the creation of a conversation before as it's currently possible).

Do you have any ideas ?

I didn’t find anything yet, or is it something impossible ?

Thanks for the informations.

Regards

Comment: Can you chat on WhatsApp with a phone number? (I mean without adding a contact?).

Comment: I have tried, but it seems impossible.

Comment: Then, I do not think that what you are asking is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their own documentation, it doesn't seem to be possible. You can read up on the possibilities here:

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

But you can't pass a phone number or any contact information with your URL request unfortunately.